# How read/write tag with ACR122U connected to a Android tablet

Tags: android, tags, nfc, tablet, acr122

I'm using an ACR122U connected to my Android Tablet which hasn't a NFC antenna, so I connect via USB the ACR. It means that I can't use the standard library of Android to use that device.

The ACS company, that provides the ACR, offers their own ACS Android Library in the next link:
http://android.acs.com.hk/

It provides a .jar but I haven't found any API explaning how use it. They supply a manual with an API in a low level code. I'm not sure that API is fine with the Android library because I think that is previous.
http://www.acs.com.hk/download-manual/419/API-ACR122U-2.02.pdf

My question is if someone can help me to read and write a tag using NDEF messages, like I did using the standard library of Android with the NFC Technology

Thanks

Comment: The ACS library is low level and incompatible with Android NFC API. Once you get the message bytes off the tag, you can use the Android NDEF code to parse the message with [new NdefMessage(bytes[])](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html#NdefMessage(byte[]))

Comment: Did you manage to get it work? possible to share some code samples?

Comment: No, I couldn't do that the Tablet recognizes the ACR122

Comment: Try https://github.com/skjolber/external-nfc-api